# How do I include a font package with a document?

Tags: fonts

I want to use the sourcecodepro tex package to typeset some figures in an academic paper, but when I submit this to the journal, I don't provide a PDF, I provide latex code and they compile it on my behalf.  This means that I cannot modify the texmf directory and must include all (non-standard) dependencies with my document.

I can easy include extra latex packages by placing the .sty file in my document directory.

*Is there a way to do something similar with a font package like sourcecodepro?*

I tried placing all of the font files and sty files in my document folder and I got an error:

```
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 SourceCodePro-Regular-tlf-t1--base
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for SourceCodePro-Regular-tlf-t1--base.
mktexpk: perhaps SourceCodePro-Regular-tlf-t1--base is missing from the map file.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
```

Comment: I guess it is not possible. The editors will clearly stick to their fonts to maintain consistent layout. You can ask them but I guess they will deny your request. Why don't you create the figures as PDFs and include them in your document? The `standalone` package is a good starting point.

Comment: What you suggest would be the fallback.  The real situation is that I've created images in an external editor and I want to refer to elements from those images from within LaTeX.  If I have to, I'll create an image of each element that I want to refer to, but this is messier than it really should be if a font package is available...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error means that the map-file is not activated. You can do it in your document with
`\pdfmapfile{=SourceCodePro.map}` (if - as I assume - you are using pdf(la)tex). The `map`-file should be in your folder too.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks.  The mysteries of latex continue to unfold.